# HDR background rendering in view-port but not in final render?

Tags: rendering

I've looked at other threads about this and they say to toggle transparency under film. It still doesn't do anything and I just have no idea why this won't work. My [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mX81KG7TBA4jVkmSquFZwomfxNF5vznc/view?usp=sharing).

View-port render
[image: View-port render]
Final render
[image: Final render]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That big plane - Plane.011 was turned off in display but not from rendering. So it occluded the reflection. You can also hide its influence in a scene by altering the object's Cycles Properties. I often turn off Camera Rays for lights so they can be in the frame but not in the shot.

[image: Object Cycles properties]